# Increased font size on mobile browsers

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web

I just noticed that the font size has increased on the main site while browsing on mobile devices. I check this on multiple devices and browsers and it was consistent.

Question titles and section titles (on profile page) now have a much larger font size which does not look great. This seems to be isolated to Stack Overflow main site.

Click on the images to see a higher quality screenshot.

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

P.S. what a pain it is to post something on my phone.

Comment: Also reported on [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391579/mobile-font-size-way-too-large). It used to be network-wide, but staff is working on it.

Comment: I think that's probably because of the Color updates thing.

Comment: It was also appearing on meta a while ago, but I think it was fixed. Hopefully this is adressed on SO soon.

Comment: Per Dan Cormier's comment on the linked MSE issue ([Mobile font-size way too large](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391579/335251)): "This is due to a change in our design system Stacks that was shipped earlier today. I have a fix en route that should be live by end of day."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for reporting @M--ßţřịƙïñĝ! This issue has been resolved.

Quoting [my response on meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/391582/163535):

> **tl;dr**: This bug has been [patched in our design system](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/releases/tag/v1.10.1) and the update has been shipped to production.
>
> ---
>
> Good catch @0stone0!
>
> This was due to a change to some `font-size` values to replace explicit pixel values with calculated values based on custom properties. To be honest, I'm not sure why the calculated values cause this issue and explicit pixel values don't. Nevertheless, changing back to explicit pixel values resolves the issue.
>
> **Note**: The cache on each network site needs to clear individually, so this may take a few days to be reflected.

Comment: Hello, We still seeing this error on SOes (Stack Overflow en Español) and a peer of communities more. I’ve entered just now to _Spanish Language_ and this bug is still visible. Using iOS/Safari

Comment: Thanks for the report @RodrigoRamírez. Quoting from [my MSE comment on this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391579/mobile-font-size-way-too-large/391582#comment1309045_391582): 
"Many network sites are requesting an outdated version of our compiled CSS without this fix. The cache may need to be purged to resolve this. I've made a request to an SRE for this, but it may be delayed until tomorrow. Sorry for the delay and thanks for being patient."